# Is it possible to buffer a set of lines in Go's x/term?

Tags: go, terminal

I'm using https://pkg.go.dev/mod/golang.org/x/term in a command-line tool. I'd like the tool to store the terminal's history to a file, and reload it when it restarts. The only way I can see appending history is through `ReadLine()` but I can't quite figure out if it's possible to even call ReadLine to give the history buffer a jump-start. Any advice?

I've been reading the code carefully, and trying to autocomplete my way into something that makes sense.

Comment: Hello, check out https://github.com/peterh/liner.

Comment: Do you mean the history of the shell before the application was even started or just the history of inputs to the application?

Comment: Thanks @marco.m, but using another module answers a different question.

Comment: @isaactfa,  thanks for asking. I meant the history of the shell before the application started.